$\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (tempered distrubutions) as dual of Schwartz $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (rapidly decreasing)
I need to prove that the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the dual of the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Most papers just define it as the dual, but I am unable to identify a real proof of this fact. Do I have to use a different definition of $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that does not involve $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ already?
Thanks

How do you define $\mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if not as the dual of Schwartz space?

Using stereographic projections / spherical distributions, just as Laurent Schwartz initially thought of it. But how am I proving that those create the dual of the usual Schwartz space?

@mathfreak include the definition of $\mathcal S'$ in the post
